# In Ionic 2 on Android, the app is visible on the lock screen if the app was active when the device locked

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm running into a major issue with an app I'm working on.  The app is running Ionic 2.  Android is the only platform affected.

Currently, if the phone goes to sleep with the app active, when the phone wakes up and is locked, the app is visible in the background (as seen in the screenshot below).  This doesn't seem like normal behavior.

***How do I stop this behavior?***

```
Cordova CLI: 6.5.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.2.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.1.4
ios-deploy version: 1.9.1 
ios-sim version: 5.0.13 
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v6.9.4
Xcode version: Xcode 8.3.1 Build version 8E1000a
```

[image: Lock screen with app active in the background]

EDIT: Added ionic/cordova version information

Comment: any help yet i have same issue

Answer (score 0):

you have to uninstall the background-mode plugin with the following command: cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-background-mode

Comment: Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question.*